# I am trying to convert Oracle view into SQL, but i am having issue with query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Oracle

```
(TO_CHAR(P.EstimatedInServiceDate, 'YYYY') =
                               (SELECT SUBSTR(ConfigurationValue, -4)
                                FROM PETE.vw_Configuration
                                WHERE configurationkey = 'CurrentPATYear'))
```

SQL - I tried to convert above code it is returning a data fine but my query is taking too long to run because of this particular chunk. If any better way to do this please let me know.

```
(Cast(DatePart(Year,P.EstimatedInServiceDate)as varchar) =
                    (SELECT right(ConfigurationValue, 4)
                     FROM Configuration
                     WHERE configurationkey = 'CurrentPATYear'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datepart()` only :

```
where datepart(year, P.EstimatedInServiceDate) = (SELECT right(ConfigurationValue, 4)
                                                  FROM Configuration
                                                  WHERE configurationkey = 'CurrentPATYear') 
                                                 )
```

Comment: thank you , I am using Datepart , I am not sure why my query is taking too long to run.

Answer (score 0):

It's a poor practice in SQL Server (or Oracle) to apply expressions to table columns in a WHERE-clause, as it makes the expression [non-Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Instead write this something like:

```
P.EstimatedInServiceDate >= 
   (SELECT ConfigurationValue 
    FROM Configuration 
    WHERE configurationkey = 'CurrentPATYear')
and 
P.EstimatedInServiceDate < dateadd(year,1,
   (SELECT ConfigurationValue 
    FROM Configuration 
    WHERE configurationkey = 'CurrentPATYear'))
```

Comment: Thank you , I missing some data when I use this. What I wanted is to compare "Year from Estimated in-service date " to "YEar from ConfigurationValue". That is the reason i was using Dateapart.